# Unknown package "com.google.android.gms" caused by "m.vr: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device."

Tags: java, android, tensorflow-lite

I am currently trying to create an Object-Detection-App with OpenCV and Tensorflow-lite. OpenCV loads in fine and Tensorflow gets loaded fine too, but opening the Camera-View results in this error:

```
Failed to get service from broker.                                                                                                java.lang.SecurityException: Unknown calling package name 'com.google.android.gms'.                                                                                                   at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3069)                                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3053)                                                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3036)                                                                                                    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)                                                                                                    at m.iv.q(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:180)                                                                                                       at m.hi.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:54)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)                                                                                                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)

Unable to update local snapshot for com.google.android.libraries.consentverifier#com.google.android.gms, may result in stale flags.                                                                                                  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: m.vr: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ed{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}                                                                                                       at m.apt.s(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:21)                                                                                                   at m.apt.get(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:5)                                                                                                      at m.arc.g(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:11)                                                                                                   at m.xe.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:1)                                                                                                     at m.xl.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:5)                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)                                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264                                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)                                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)                                                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)                                                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: m.vr: 17: 17: API: Phenotype.API is not available on this device. Connection failed with: ed{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null, message=null}                                                                                                      at m.vs.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:13)                                                                                                    at m.apb.f(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:3)                                                                                                    at m.apd.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:139)                                                                                                    at m.aqn.execute(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:1)                                                                                                      at m.apt.q(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:1)                                                                                                    at m.apt.m(:com.google.android.gms.policy_tflite_dynamite_dynamite@234200807@234200803065.583380261.583380261:96)                                                                                                    ... There's More
```

I tried updating all dependencies and tried out different versions of every dependency but nothing seems to affect that.

Here is my build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
}
android {
    namespace = "com.tund.objectdetection"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.tund.objectdetection"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.3.1")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.1")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:2.3.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")

    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.1"))
    implementation(group="com.fasterxml.jackson.core", name="jackson-core", version="2.16.0")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2")
    implementation("com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0")

    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.0")
    implementation("org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.9.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-gpu:16.1.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-tflite-support:16.0.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-phenotype:17.0.0")
    implementation(project(":opencv"))
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
}
```

Top Level build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("com.android.library") version "8.2.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.20" apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.0" apply false
}
```

I checked for permission of the app, it can access wifi and internet aswell as use the camera.
Playstore is also uptodate on every device tested.
This error only gets thrown on physical devices, an emulated device only hints at the issue with this:

```
Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.tflite_dynamite not found.

Considering local module com.google.android.gms.tflite_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.tflite_dynamite:0

Cannot initialize interpreter: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.tflite_dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
```

Adding `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.gms" />` to my manifest prevents the app from launching entirely:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: androidx.startup.StartupException: androidx.startup.StartupException: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer cannot be cast to androidx.startup.Initializer`

I am out of ideas of what to do and there's not really any other solution online besides "update your dependencies or report to google"

Does anybody know a fix or a hint in the right direction?

Comment: What Android device do you use for testing? Has it Google Play Services installed?

Comment: @Robert I am using a Samsung Galaxy Tab S9 Ultra and a Google Pixel 8 as physical devices to test on. My emulator is a Pixel 3a.